# strings casting to negative integer T-sql

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

I learned in my SQL course last week how to turn a string into an integer. The table we used for this was timezone-based, so it was '-5' hours offset.

In order to do this we had to cast the string to a `DECIMAL` and then to an SMALLINT.  It was pretty simple once I knew that, but that's not where my question lies.

What I'm curious about is why a `SMALLINT` wouldn't take a negative sign but A decimal could do it. according to the specs, a `SMALLINT` still can go to -32768. Does anyone know if this persists in all coding languages or is it just SQL-specific? As well as what won't allow it to be cast.

Comment: `DECLARE @s SMALLINT = CAST('-5' AS SMALLINT)` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would bother doing any casting to begin with? According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (see table 1/3 down the page), T-SQL supports implicit conversion between varchar and smallint.

```
DECLARE @negative_varchar VARCHAR(10) = '-5'

DECLARE @negative_smallint SMALLINT = CONVERT(SMALLINT, @negative_varchar)

DECLARE @negative_smallint_implicit SMALLINT = @negative_varchar

SELECT @negative_varchar, @negative_smallint, @negative_smallint_implicit
```

Produces

```
---------- ------ ------
-5         -5     -5
```

Answer (score -2):

no this is what im saying  (declare @s as nvarchar
@s=-5

(50) = CAST (@s AS SMALL INT)

again you have to cast from decimal then small int. im asking about the underlying code behind the process.

such as does one of the bytes hold whether a number is positive or negative etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is completely incomprehensible?